# Options for TFS

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, msdn

We are bringing in interns in a couple weeks to augment the team over the summer. Our application is .NET 4.5 and source control via TFS. The interns role will be mainly focused on HTML / Javascript but we are struggling on how we are going to integrate them into source control.

My question is without buying every intern (who will be here for only a couple months) an MSDN subscription with Visual Studio Pro do we have any options for TFS?

Answer (score 4):

You can buy a TFS CAL separately from MSDN: http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/Visual-Studio-Team-Foundation-Server-2013-User-CAL/productID.284831700

Also you could use VSO which gives you 5 free users, and only costs $20/month/user after that:
https://www.visualstudio.com/pricing/visual-studio-online-pricing-vs

Comment: Thanks for the TFS CAL Link I would consider it an option. Wish we could use the VSO but its against company policy at this time.